# Approximate year in which Outer Dark is occurring?

Tags: cormac-mccarthy, outer-dark

The Wikipedia article indicates that it occurs at the turn of the 20th century and I think I recall that also from the cover of a copy I read.

There is remarkably little technology mentioned -- I do not recall an automobile -- people are still using horses/mules. And there is no mention of a telephone but the area is very rural and poor -- I would guess even in the 1950s in Appalachia people might not have been using phones or automobiles.

We get some idea perhaps of the time based on the price of things and wages, but again this could be due to poverty. The brother also purchases a "dope" which I believe is the term for a Coca Cola, but I am not sure when this term was current.

Interestingly, the sister meets a kindly attorney who sounds like a more modern character than the other people we encounter. The attorney invites the sister to wait for his office-building mate but McCarthy seems to carefully avoid mentioning whether illumination is provided by electricity or flame.

The doctor also seems like a more contemporary character, like his friend the attorney. The doctor does betray what sounds like a superstitious belief about the sister's condition -- he asserts that because she is still lactating that her infant is still alive. I may be misinterpreting -- he may simply mean that the baby had been born more recently.

Anyway, unlike Blood Meridian, there is no explicit mention of year.

However, the brother encounters an auctioneer who is holding an event and he mentions two musical acts, one of which is called "The Willis Brothers" and the other is something like "Little Oud" but I am unsure of the spelling. The former act seems to have been a real group which started in the 1930s. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Willis_Brothers -- strange CM threw this real group in -- one member at least lived all the way to the 1990s.)

It is curious to me that CM is so deliberate in avoiding mentioning time and place. Perhaps his idea is to show the reader that in parts of the USA, people lived very much as they always had and perhaps also the year was not something they kept in mind much.

But the musical group seems to establish that the story occurred at the earliest in the 1930s, and indeed prices and wages indicate that the Great Depression might still be in progress.

Moreover, I have noticed that almost every story or movie occurring in the decade or so after WW2 mentions this at least in passing (and certainly if during WW2, this is usually explicitly mentioned) and this implies to me that the story occurs in the 1930s.

Is there any reason to believe that it occurred much earlier -- turn of the century would have been 3 or 4 decades before?

I note that many TV shows never mention the current year (this was discussed in Movies and TV about various 1960s and 1950s shows -- about "I Love Lucy" one poster mentioned that when they did show a calendar, the year was blocked) which I understand was a choice made so that old shows would not be "dated", literally and they could be reshown. Even for shows set in the 19th century, like "Bonanza", we know it is post Civil War but I think for some reason a specific year is rarely used.

But in literature, there is a lot of variation -- certainly some writers are very clear about time and place. CM mentioned cities and dates throughout "Blood Meridian" but not so in "Outer Dark". Perhaps besides what I mentioned before it contributed to a sort of "fairy tale" feel for the story, although I have not read him comment about "Outer Dark" at all.

Comment: I am not a fan of Bonanza, but I know it had special episodes with flashbacks to the births of Ben's three sons decades before the Civil War.  And I believe that one episode involved the  Battle(s) of Pyramid Lake  (May and June 1860) and another episode involved the pony express (April 1860-October 1861).  So some Bonanza episodes happen before or during the Civil War.